# WPF Hide TextBlock if one collection count equal another

Tags: wpf, textblock, datatrigger

Hullo,

I'm setting up my WPF pane to display some text based on the values of several view model collections that are bound to a ListView.

The text is displayed as in a stack panel which displays the number of views in a collection, followed by another TextBlock which displays if any are hidden.

This is worked out by the following bindings:

Browser.Count = this is the total number of views

BrowserItemCollectionView.Count = this is the number of views hidden

Basically, I want the text to hide if Browser.Count == BrowserItemCollectionView.Count

This is the XAML code

```
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                    <TextBlock x:Name="TotalCount"
                               Foreground="#FF6F6F6F">
                        <Run Text="{Binding Path=Browser.Count, Mode=OneWay}" />
                        <Run Text=" Views" />
                    </TextBlock>
                    
                    <TextBlock x:Name="SearchCount"
                               Foreground="#FF6F6F6F">
                        <TextBlock.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">

                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=BrowserItemCollectionView.Count, Mode=OneWay}"
                                                 Value="---SOME CLEVER BINDING HERE---">
                                        <Setter Property="UIElement.Visibility"
                                                Value="Hidden" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>

                            </Style>
                        </TextBlock.Style>
                        <Run Text=", ("></Run>
                        <Run Text="{Binding Path=BrowserItemCollectionView.Count, Mode=OneWay}"></Run>
                        <Run Text=" visible.)"></Run>
                    </TextBlock>

                </StackPanel>
```

So I thought this would easy enough to change the DataTrigger above with:

```
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=BrowserItemCollectionView.Count, Mode=OneWay}"
                             Value="{Binding Path=Browser.Count, Mode=OneWay}">
                       <Setter Property="UIElement.Visibility"
                               Value="Hidden" />
                </DataTrigger>
```

But this doesn't work as the error states that a Value cannot be set to a binding...

What would be the simplest way of doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DataTrigger` with `MultiBinding`.

```
<DataTrigger Value="True">
    <DataTrigger.Binding>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyCustomConverter}">
            <Binding Path="BrowserItemCollectionView.Count" />
            <Binding Path="Browser.Count" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </DataTrigger.Binding>
    <Setter Property="UIElement.Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
</DataTrigger>
```

Bind to two properties and use `MultiValueConverter` to check if values of those properties are equal.

```
public class MyCustomConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values.Length != 2)
        {
            return false;
        }
        var value1 = values[0];
        var value2 = values[1];

        return value1.Equals(value2);

    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The second option is to create a bool property on your view model and make a logic in your view model which will set that property to true/false. Bind to that property in `DataTrigger`.

```
private bool collectionsEqual;
public bool CollectionsEqual
{
    get { return collectionsEqual; }
    set
    {
        collectionEqual = value;
        OnPropertyChanged()
    }
}
...
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CollectionsEqual}" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="UIElement.Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: Thanks. I get the error 'Cannot set MultiBinding because MultiValueConverter must be specified' am I missing something? Cheers.

Comment: @Archie456 Did you set MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyCustomConverter}"? Does your converter implement System.Windows.Data.IMultiValueConverter interface?

Comment: @Archie456 If it helps you can mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: I tried, but was told my rep is below 15 and so not allowed to accept answers for some reason... my current rep level is 13....